# springboot restcontroller not called

Tags: rest, spring-boot

The problem is that my rest controller is not getting called.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.company.base" })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @Autowired
    private SusbscriberRepository susbscriberRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<SubscriberResource> findAll() {
     ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscriber/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SubscriberResource> findSubscriber(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
      ...
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Grenty</name>
    <description>Grenty project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>SA Technologies</name>
        <url>www.satechnologies.com</url>
    </organization>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.jpdigital</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-hibernate-5.1.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dialects>
                        <param>postgresql9</param>
                    </dialects>
                    <packages>
                        <param>com.company.base.model</param>
                    </packages>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/docs/sql</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>gen-ddl</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the Springboot start log, these url are mapped.

I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

Even spring example is not working: `gs-actuator-service-master`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when you make an HTTP request to one of those endpoints?  Do you get a Response?  If so, what is the HTTP Status?  Also, I don't see the spring-boot-starter-web dependency...  That is the most conventional approach.

Comment: I get whitelabel error page and inside 404 HTTP error.

Comment: And what about the missing spring-boot-starter-web dependency?  If you could share a minimal example app on GitHub that reproduces that problem, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Three things may have problems

1. `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` & `spring-boot-starter-web` libs could be  missing.
2. Your controller must under the `com.company.base` package because of you defined `scanBasePackages`.
3. Spring boot Application must run with `SpringBootServletInitializer`. This case will only required if your run as Java Application, that not required if you are running from mvn command.

Please add libraries & update your `Application.java` and try again.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: In my case, spring-boot-starter-web was missing. Thanks for pointing out that!

Answer (score 0):

Remove scanBasePackages = { "com.company.base" } if the controller is under boot app package or sub package.
Or include package of main class as well in component scan.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. 
I added *spring-mvc* dependency.

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.3.RELEASE"
```

By default, the main class should be in the root package. I put the main class into a different package, so I had to component scan and add other components to be available.

```
package root.package1

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"root"})
```

public class WebAppMain {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebAppMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move controller class into subpackage of the application class.

```
like 
    com.company.base for Application class
    com.company.base.controller for DataController class
```

then spring boot will scan controller automatically.